# Is this Security/Authentication ok for my REST API?

Tags: rest, authentication, ssl

I have a restful API, and I have assigned them all a userId and a secret key.  To call the API they provide those credentials for the HTTP `Basic Authentication` credentials over SSL.

Is this safe enough?

Comment: That's very difficult to answer. Depends on too many factors. Is it public? Internal? How 'safe' do you want it to be?

Comment: Safe enough = to run on the internet.  I'm not providing banking services here thankfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Authentication is secure over SSL.  Worry not, the username / password portion of the HTTP packet will be encrypted when using SSL.

Comment: Should the users always pass basic authentication in, or is this something that only has to be done once?  (or would they just detect the 401 redirect?)